# Class loading from plist vulnerability

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, jailbreak

I'm currently auditing an iOS application and I came across this scenario that made me wonder whether it could be exploited somehow.

Here's the scenario: there's a plist containing a class name, namely a `UIViewController` subclass name, as a string.

Such string is then loaded and used to retrieve the matching class like follows:

```
NSString *className = ... // loaded from plist 
UIViewController *vc = [(UIViewController *)[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initWithNibName:className bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

I'm wondering whether it would be possible (on a jailbroken device) to tamper with the plist and have the application to load an arbitrary `UIViewController` subclass.

Any thoughts?

Comment: By modifying the plist inputing an arbitrary class name, the above code would blindly try to load that class instead of the intended one. I'd like to figure out whether this is a possible scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a vulnerability, but as @LonelyDeveloper said in a comment, I think that's the least of your worries with a jailbroken device.

It's true that with the code you posted, if someone modifies the app's Info.plist - which they **can** do on a jailbroken phone - the app will load another subclass of `UIViewController`.  Now, if that's all they do, then it will only be a subclass that exists **already** in the app, or a library that the app already loads.

Doing this may simply cause the app to function incorrectly.  It doesn't seem like a great way to make the app do something completely malicious.

Your app would have to have some *other* flaw.  For example, let's say this is a banking app that caches data.  The app opens with a login view controller.  The account view controller shows sensitive information, but the app won't let you see the account view controller without successfully entering a password through the login view controller.  With this plist loading, if the plist says to load the `LoginViewController`, and the attacker modifies the plist to specify `AccountViewController`, it's possible that access could be gained to information that should be protected.  But, I think this scenario shows a *combination* of flaws.

However, if a malicious user (someone stole your phone) or a malicious download from Cydia installed a [MobileSubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) tweak, then they **could** load arbitrary subclasses of `UIViewController`, not just the wrong view controller from your app.  But, this also allows them to do this even without the plist class loading.  MobileSubstrate tweaks can using *hooking* to inject all kinds of new code, virtually wherever they want.

So, this vulnerability already exists, and you have to trust that the jailbreak community, and jailbreak repos, can adequately protect you from malicious software.  This is why I basically only install Cydia, SBSettings, Activator, and Saurik's unix command line tools on my jailbroken devices.

Comment: thank you for the accurate answer. Of course the scenario is a little bit more complicated than the one I exposed, for instance the app has already some anti-swizzling protection. That's why I was concerned that such a naive flaw would make them useless. However it sounds like a minor concern with respect to other vulnerabilities deriving from be running in a jailbroken environment. Thank you again.